# pyobjc and wx crash when program exits ends

Tags: python, objective-c, segmentation-fault, wxpython, pyobjc

Similar to this question [wxPython + PyObjC causes app to crash at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407570/wxpython-pyobjc-causes-app-to-crash-at-the-end) however there code has more superfluous code.

I have the following two samples of code, the latter crashes the former runs fine.

**The only difference in the code is the order of the imports.**

### **This code runs fine.**

```
import time

# note that the line is before this is so the code does work this is the only
# change that seems to matter
# need the following line to be AFTER wx import otherwise runs fine
import objc # or import Foundation or probably any objc library

import wx



# need the following line
app = wx.App(redirect=False)

# sleep shows it is ONLY when the code finally ends not before
time.sleep(3)
# you don't even need the MainLoop call
```

### **This code runs segfaults when program stops running.**

```
import time

import wx
# need this line to be AFTER wx import otherwise runs fine
import objc # or import Foundation or probably any objc library


# need the following line
app = wx.App(redirect=False)

# sleep shows it is ONLY when the code finally ends not before
time.sleep(3)
# you don't even need the MainLoop call
```

### **How to replicate**

1. Make sure pyobjc is installed and you can import objc
2. Make sure wxPython is installed (it seems both 2.9 and 3.0 are effected)
3. run command python *file*

Comment: it took me a while to see the difference in the two files ... but this is a great question imho

Comment: Yep it is literally just switching two lines and it causes a segfault which is rather amazing if not annoying.

Answer (score 0):

### **Temporary Solution**

Note: This only works in specific cases and is still rather a hack and so shouldn't be used always.

This seems to work but is distasteful as it only fixes the error not the underlining code problem

Make sure you import objc **before you import wx** or **any of your libraries do** (for example I had to do it before I used twisted networking library too as I installed a reactor that worked with wx (and so it imported wx)).